# Removed <Header> from printing on every page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, printing

My program requires that a printer friendly version be developed to override browser print functionality.
Our banner is located within the `<header></header>` tags and displays at the top of every page when printing, **only in IE**.
In Chrome the banner is only located at the top of the first page.

Is this the intended functionality of the two browsers? We would prefer that it only display at the top of the first page (Chrome's default). Is it possible to override the IE functionality?

Comment: What is the CSS of the header in question? is it a `position:fixed;` header?

Comment: @media print{ header{display:none}; #homepage header{display:block;} }

Comment: And Firefox,Where are you?